# How to fixed block size of a dropdown-Menu

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu of libraries. Each library may have sub-objects into them (they are in the attribute . Internal Elements) or not. When i hover over a library with instances it shows another menu to the right. The problem is that the first menu is changing sizes when this happens making it ugly and when i hover over the last library (without instances) it changes size at the same time and blocks the menu al together.
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI6Gv.png)
The HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-11">
    <a href="#"
         class="list-group-item clearfix"
         (click)="onSelected()">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{picture.Name}}</h4>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div *ngIf="dropdownflag">
      <app-xml-element *ngFor="let component of components" [component]="component"></app-xml-element>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1.5">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div *ngFor="let librarie of libraries">
          <div *ngIf="librarie.InternalElements.length>=1; else empty">
            <div class="right">
              <a class="dropright" >{{librarie.Name}}</a>
              <div class="right-content">
                <div *ngFor="let instance of librarie.InternalElements">
                  <a (click)="addElement(librarie,instance)">{{instance.Name}}</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>          
          <ng-template #empty><a href="#"(click)="addElement(librarie,librarie)">{{librarie.Name}}</a></ng-template>
        </div>          
      </div>
    </div>
    <button role="button" (click)="dropdown()" *ngIf="picture.InternalElements.length>=1"><span class="caret"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding:5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}

/*Right menu container*/
.right {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* content on 2nd menu*/
.right-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  left:160px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/*ensure that a has the same format as previous class a*/
.right-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
/*hoverable a tag to show 2nd menu*/
.dropright {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
/* Show the 2nd menu on hover right */
.right:hover .right-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! If you hit Ctrl-M and copy your HTML and CSS into the appropriate panels, you'll get a runnable version of your code, which will help everyone to troubleshoot your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello buddy the reason behind your dropdown not working properly is because you are using `relative` in your child div here is the code hopefully its good for you

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
  .dropbtn {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding:5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  }

  /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
    .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
    .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    }

    /* Links inside the dropdown */
    .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    }

    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

    /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

    /* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}

    /*Right menu container*/
    .right {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    /* content on 2nd menu*/
    .right-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 152px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;}

    /*ensure that a has the same format as previous class a*/
    .right-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    }
    /*hoverable a tag to show 2nd menu*/
    .dropright {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    }
    /* Show the 2nd menu on hover right */
    .right:hover .right-content,.right:focus .right-content{
    display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-11">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix" (click)="onSelected()">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{picture.Name}}</h4>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div *ngIf="dropdownflag">
      <app-xml-element *ngFor="let component of components" [component]="component"></app-xml-element>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1.5">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div *ngFor="let librarie of libraries">
          <div *ngIf="librarie.InternalElements.length>=1; else empty">
            <div class="right">
              <a class="dropright">{{librarie.Name}}</a>
              <div class="right-content">
                <div *ngFor="let instance of librarie.InternalElements">
                  <a (click)="addElement(librarie,instance)">{{instance.Name}}</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ng-template #empty><a href="#" (click)="addElement(librarie,librarie)">{{librarie.Name}}</a></ng-template>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button role="button" (click)="dropdown()" *ngIf="picture.InternalElements.length>=1"><span
        class="caret"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot it really helped. Just a quick note. the width of the drop-right must be equal to the width of the drop-down-content. otherwise it leaves a "blank" space that is not consider part of the 2nd menu and causes it to drop the 2nd menu when you move your mouse from the 1st to the 2nd one.

Comment: @gagnar now run the above snippet it is resolved your further issue at first i only resolved your space issue beside approved the answer as i solved the query thanks brother